# How do I post something to facebook from iOS with latest Facebook SDK?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, post

I'm trying to post a simple url to facebook from within my Native iOS App. What I do is this:

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:FB_APP_ID andDelegate:delegate];
```

then at some point

```
[facebook authorize:permissions];
```

at this point my app quits and it gets me to safari and to the permissions page instead of presenting me a login-dialog (inside my app) where I login and then hit post or something an just post to my wall.

I'm pretty sure this is a simple question but since this is the first time I'm doing facebook integration it is a pain for me configuring it and the docs don't help to much.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you definitely need to remove redirection to Safari or Facebook app, you should open the FBConnect Facebook.h class and find the following method:

```
- (void)authorizeWithFBAppAuth:(BOOL)tryFBAppAuth
                    safariAuth:(BOOL)trySafariAuth {
```

there you need to state that you do not want to be redirected anywhere, to do that set those two bools to NO

```
    - (void)authorizeWithFBAppAuth:(BOOL)tryFBAppAuth
                        safariAuth:(BOOL)trySafariAuth {
tryFBAppAuth = NO;
trySafariAuth = NO;
```

Next, to post something to wall, you have two options. One is broken - the standard facebook dialog window, which will bring the keyboard BEHIND the actual webview once you show any `UIAlertView` ANYWHERE in your application, therefore do NOT use it. Instead use your own custom interface with a simple `UITextView` area and a push to wall outlet button. Here's the method that you'll need in order to post to wall from your custom view:

```
- (void)facebookPostToWallWithMessage:(NSString *)message {
  sharedInstance.facebookDelegate = delegate;
  NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 message, @"message", // The status message
                                 nil];

  pushMessageRequest = [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                                            andParams:params
                                        andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                                          andDelegate:self];
}
```

And here's the delegation methods that you'll need in order to inform users that they've posted an update or to inform them that it has failed:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
  if (request == pushMessageRequest) {
    NSLog(@"message has been posted, inform delegate");
  }
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
  if (request == pushMessageRequest) {
//failed to post message, inform delegate
    //[facebookDelegate facebookFailedToPostToWallWithMessage:error.localizedDescription];
  }
}
```

Comment: do you know how to stop redirects with the new facebook-ios-sdk update? They removed these functions by the looks of it? Id be really greatful!

Comment: I don't really know how to, but those redirects are becoming a common thing in all the apps, so you should bother about them too much. It's better to carry on with the flow